# UISearchController in UITabBarController status bar issues

Tags: ios, uikit

I have been having this issue with the status bar and tab bar.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
self.searchResultsController = [BZDashboardSearchResultsController new];

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];
self.searchController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:self.searchController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

I want to hide the tab bar place the search bar under the status bar. My view controller hierarchy looks like this:

```
UITabBarController
   --UINavigationController
       ---View Controller where the above code is executed.
```

In my app delegate, I set my UITabBarController subclass as the root view controller:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarViewController;
```

The init method of the subclass is this:

```
-(instancetype)init {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    UINavigationController *workspaceNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.workspaceController];

    self.userProfileViewController.showLogoutButton = YES;
    UINavigationController *userProfileNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.userProfileViewController];

    self.viewControllers = @[workspaceNavigationController, userProfileNavigationController];
  }

  return self;
}
```

self.workspaceController has a search button in its navigation bar the code that presets UiSearchController.

Comment: please post the screenshot of your storyboard

Comment: Did not use storyboard...everything is in code.

Comment: show us the code how you add the navigation controller, tab bar and the view controller and how you present them

Comment: @Mr.T updated with code.